# Add dependency Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, dependencies

I'm trying to add a new dependency to my Bitcoin Core fork. The dependency is [Rapidcheck](https://github.com/emil-e/rapidcheck), a property based testing framework.

I've added a file called `rapidcheck.mk` inside of `depends/packages` with the following content

```
package=rapidcheck

$(package)_version:1.0

$(package)_download_path:https://github.com/Christewart/rapidcheck/releases/download/1.0

$(package)_file_name:rapidcheck-1.0.tar.gz

$(package)_sha256_hash:c228dc21ec24618bfb6afa31d622d1f4ea71168f04ee499e1ffcfc63cd5833f4

define $(package)_preprocess_cmds
  mkdir build
endef

define $(package)_config_cmds
  cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$(build_prefix)/bin ..
endef

define $(package)_build_cmds
  $(MAKE)
endef
```

I've also modified the `depends/packages/packages.mk` file to add `rapidcheck`

Now it looks like this

```
packages:=boost openssl libevent rapidcheck
darwin_packages:=zeromq
linux_packages:=zeromq
native_packages := native_ccache native_comparisontool

qt_native_packages = native_protobuf
qt_packages = qrencode protobuf

qt_x86_64_linux_packages:=qt expat dbus libxcb xcb_proto libXau xproto freetype fontconfig libX11 xextproto libXext xtrans
qt_i686_linux_packages:=$(qt_x86_64_linux_packages)

qt_darwin_packages=qt
qt_mingw32_packages=qt


wallet_packages=bdb

upnp_packages=miniupnpc

darwin_native_packages = native_biplist native_ds_store native_mac_alias

ifneq ($(build_os),darwin)
darwin_native_packages += native_cctools native_cdrkit native_libdmg-hfsplus
endif
```

I've run `make clean && make` after doing all this and added the `include <rapidcheck.h>` to a file in the `test/` dir. I get an error saying that the file could not be found. What step(s) am I missing?

You can see my commit for these changes on my bitcoin core fork [here](https://github.com/Christewart/bitcoin/commit/1c6a71a212f9684070194697a51935affb270e03)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to build the dependency:

```
cd ./depends/
make
```

And then tell bitcoin where to find the dependency:

```
cd ../
./configure --prefix=`pwd`/depends/x86_whatever_your_current_arch_is
```

Further information:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/depends/README.md#usage